# What Desktop is setup in my Debian Machine

Tags: linux, debian

I have a desktop Environment in a Debian Machine.

What is the Shell Command can I use to know what Desktop Environment I have in my Debian machine ? To know if is it KDE, GNOME, XFCE...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220055/what-desktop-is-setup-in-my-debian-machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> sudo apt-get install wmctrl
>
> wmctrl -m | grep "Name:" | awk '{print $2}'

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/125062/how-can-i-find-which-desktop-enviroment-i-am-using

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
```

it gives current desktop environment

current desktop

```
echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

Comment: In my Gnome 3 desktop environment, `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` gives `default`. Does not look helpful.

Comment: use: echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP

Comment: Well, this one does not exist.

Comment: sudo apt-get install wmctrl

Comment: `vmctrl` can only give the name of the window manager currently in use, I am not sure there is a one-to-one correspondence between window manager and desktop environment.

Comment: wmctrl -m gives Name , Class, etc

Comment: On my Debian 7, Gnome 3.4 system, `wmctrl -m` gives "Name: Mutter
Class: N/A". It is not very helpful, unless I can make sure that there is a one-to-one correspondence between window manager and desktop environment.